# Matlab split image to 10x10 cells

Tags: arrays, image, matlab, divide

I have an image represented by a matrix. Let's say it's 21x23 matrix.

How can I divide a matrix into 10 rows and 10 columns. They don't have to be the same size though.

There is a function mat2cell but I don't know how to use it

Comment: What's the real requirement for the size of each cell? You want 10 rows x 10 columns but not necessarily...I don't understand exactly what you need. Please provide more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's your data be stored in inputmat.

First, you'd have to compute the dimensions of sub-matrices. For example, they could be:

```
rows = diff(floor(linspace(0,21,11)))
cols = diff(floor(linspace(0,23,11)))
```

and then you execute:

```
cellmatrix = mat2cell(inputmat,rows, cols);
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the number of cells to specify in each dimension doesn't evenly divide.  MATLAB will throw you an error in this case.  For the case of the OP, they want to create 10 x 10 cells of **uneven** sizes from a 21 x 23 image.  You need to do something else, or modify the way you are calling `mat2cell` to account for cells of uneven sizes.

Comment: I think what's desired is `rows = diff(floor(linspace(0,21,11)))`

Comment: @Ben Voigt: This is the correct way to compute the number of rows. I'll update my solution according to your comment.

Comment: You might want to generalize: `rows_in_input` (= `size(inputmat,1)`), and `output_stripes+1` (or similar names)

Comment: Thanks for updating.  This will now work. +1 from me.